# Event manager for Wordpress two columns with flex problem

Tags: css, wordpress, events, plugins, flexbox

I'm working on a WordPress site where the client wants to have their events in displayed in a day to day format using the Event Manager plugin for WordPress, and so that the events are aranged in columns of two (this is how it looks now: https://ibb.co/cwfg6V).

I tried doing it all with flex but the problem accures when both the date and the two columns of events that I have gets wrapped inside the `#em-wrapper` (by default) and I don't want the date to be flexed with the event/event columns at all (because then they are on the same line as the image shows in the link.) I can't change the way how the date is placed inside the parent div becuase it is handeled by the Event Manager plugin, the only thing I can do is to create classes for everything.

[An image of the HTML formating that I can do in for a single events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtsf2.png)

A simple example of how it is done.

```css
#em-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.event_container {
   display: flex;
   flex: 1;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   max-width: 300px;
   padding: 0 5px 30px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="em-wrapper">
  <h1 class="event_date">1.1.2018</h1>
  <div class="event_container">An event</div>
  
  <h1 class="event_date">2.1.2018</h1>
  <div class="event_container">Another event</div>
</div>
```

I hope that you guys can understand what I mean thanks!

Comment: _“and I can't change the HTML of the event manager plugin of course”_ - why not? https://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/using-template-files/

Comment: _“But I only want the .event_container to be flexed, not the date […], only whats inside the #em-wrapper”_ - you’re not even making sense here, _both_ are inside the #em-wrapper …

Comment: The only thing I cant edit is the .event_container, I can't add a new parent div to the both of the events, if I try that then only one of the events/columns will be selected and I need to select both of the columns and flex it so that they wrap correctly, and not flex the date.

Comment: Sorry, but that does make even less sense to me now. Please give a proper example of how you _want_ this to look first of all.

Comment: Ah sorry it's difficult to explain in text... so the Event manager let's me format how I want each event to look (look at the image that I added to the post) in it have I added some classes for the image and the text. This all gets wrapped inside the #em-wrapper, and I can't change where the date is located inside or outside the #em-wrapper it is handeld by the plugin

Comment: I meant how you want this to look in the front-end, what visual effect do you want to achieve by applying flexbox?

Comment: https://ibb.co/cwfg6V

Comment: So what does the actual HTML structure look like for such a situation where you have two events on the same date? Presumably it still contains the date element twice? That is a structure that is really _extremely_ unsuitable for what you want to achieve. If you really can’t modify the server-side logic to output this in a more suitable structure, then you could do it on the client side via JavaScript, loop over this mess and insert a grouping element and transplant the event data elements into those …

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for the answer. I will look into a JavaScript solution, or any other that would solve this in a better way. Thank you again, and sorry for the confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with flexbox.

The `#em-wrapper` gets: `display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;`

...and the `.event_date` gets: `flex: 1 0 100%;`

...and the `.event_containe` gets: `flex: 1 1 50%;`